# Freemarker "Expected a hash, but this evaluated to a string"

Tags: freemarker

I'm using Freemarker as an addition with OpenOffice, to process documents with variables.

Therefore, in this case, I want an adress with either a contact person (if there is one) or just the normal contact details (adress).

```
[#function GetAdr]
    [#return (recipient)!"unbekannt" /]
[/#function] 


[#function GetAdrWithContact]
    [#return (GetAdr().contact)!"unbekannt" /]
[/#function]

[#if (GetAdrWithContact().adress)?? ]
[#if GetAdr().name??]${(GetAdr().name)?xml}<text:line-break />[/#if][@Adr GetAdrWithContact() /]
[#elseif (GetAdr().adress)?? ][@Adr GetAdr() /] [/#if]
[/#macro]
```

If I want to use this code, I get the

> Expected a hash, but this evaluated to a string

error, only for the case if there is no contact person though. It works, as long as there is a contact person.

Edit: I tried to check `GetAdrWithContact().adress)` with `?has_content` or `?is_string`, neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!` operator (and `?has_content`) only handless nulls and missing values, not type errors. And indeed it's strange when you chose a default value that differs in type from what would be there when the value isn't `null`. Certainly you should use `{}` (empty hash) as the default, or something like that. Something that's similar to the real thing. Then `GetAdr().name??` and such won't be an error.

Comment: Thank you! I guess you could call me stupid. Now everything works as charming as it should! :-)